# Templated outer class static member initialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following:

```
// TreeMap.h

template<class K, class V>
class TreeMap {
public:
    enum Color {
        BLACK,
        RED
    }; 

    class TreeMapNode {
        K& key;
        V& value;
        Color c; 
    public:
        TreeMapNode(K&,V&);
        TreeMapNode(std::pair<K,V>);
        K& getKey(void); 
        V& getValue(void);
        Color getColor(void); 

        void setColor(Color); 
    };
private:
    TreeMapNode* root; 
    static TreeMapNode nil; 

// TreeMap.cpp

template<class K, class V>
TreeMap<K,V>::TreeMapNode* TreeMap<K,V>::nil (NULL);
```

I can't seem to get the syntax of initializing the static TreeMap::nil member correctly. I eventually want the TreeMap::nil member to be an empty TreeMap::TreeMapNode (sentinel node).

Comment: Did you try declaring your member as a `TreeMapNode*` rather than a `TreeMapNode` (not the absent `*`)?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet:

```
template<class K, class V>
TreeMap<K,V>::TreeMapNode* TreeMap<K,V>::nil (NULL);
```

defines a pointer called `nil`, plus it uses a dependent type and you need to tell the compiler that. You probably want:

```
template<class K, class V>
typename TreeMap<K,V>::TreeMapNode TreeMap<K,V>::nil (NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you are lacking a `*` in the declaration of the static member: you define a `TreeMapNode*` but you declared a `TreeMapNode`.

That said, note that this probably doesn't quite give you want you want:
 1. if you leave the definition of the static member in the header you will get multiply defined symbols if you ever use the `TreeMap` with the same template arguments in different translation units
 2. if you move the definition to a non-header file you need to add explicit instantiations of the static member for every combination of template arguments

In general, there is limited use of objects as `static` members of a class template. However, you can create a `static` member function which returns the object instead, e.g.

```
static TreeMapNode* nil() { static TreeMapnNode* rc(0); return rc; }
```

There are many variations thereof e.g. to return a reference or a const reference and you might want to define the function outside the defintion, etc. The `static` object in the above code is really only needed if you want to return a reference to it. Otherwise you can just return `0` instead.